# A command for outputting a list of parameter values in a Manipulate interface

Tags: functions, dynamic, manipulate, interface

I am looking for a command that will output a list of values that correspond to the current parameter values manually set on a particular `Manipulate` interface.

For example, lets say I create an interactive interface using this code:

```
 Manipulate[
 Plot[
 A*Sin[f*t + p],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}],
 {A, 0, 1}, {f, 1, 10}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Then suppose I use the `Manipulate` interface to set the parameters to some values I like as in the instance shown in the this screen cap:

[image]

What I would like to do now is input some command that will output these parameter values that the interface is currently set to (in this case, A = .5, f = 6, p = 1.4).

Ideally, I would like a `List` in a new cell of the form

```
{0.5, 6, 1.4}
```

Perhaps some kind of `Dynamic` automatic updating feature would be nice too.

This will allow me to continue being lazy and not have to enter these values individually when I refer to them in later code. Thanks to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to introduce a `global` variable storing the `Manipulate` variables:

```
Manipulate[
 global = {A, f, p};
 Plot[A*Sin[f*t + p], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}],
 {A, 0, 1}, {f, 1, 10}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

From now on, we can query `global` in a different cell any time. If wrapped into `Dynamic`, it will be updated as the `Manipulate` is manipulated.

```
Dynamic@global
```

Comment: sometimes it is possible to overcomplicate the problem but this is certainly the most straight forward approach.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Very simple indeed! Thank you

Answer (score 8):

If you just want `A`, `f`, and `p` dynamically displayed all the time and printed when desired then:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Row[{Button["print", 
      CellPrint[
       TextCell[Grid[{{"A =", A}, {"f =", f}, {"p =", p}}], "Text", 
        ShowStringCharacters -> False]]], {A, f, p}}],
   Plot[A*Sin[f*t + p], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}]
   }],
 {A, 0, 1},
 {f, 1, 10},
 {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Because the values within the `Manipulate` are localized it is unclear what you mean by referring to them (the values) in later code.

One thing to do, if your application is to save these values for later use, would be to bookmark the settings which you can do once you click the little icon in the top right hand corner:

[image]

From there give the bookmark a name:

[image]

I called it "my settings", so now you can revert to these settings from any state simply by selecting "my settings".

[image]

You can paste the bookmarked settings if you want to use the values in other code. Another thing could be to paste a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: These methods definitely accomplish my objective and also offer a greater utility than I originally intended. Until now I was unaware of this "Bookmarks" feature that was always just a click away. Thank you for relieving me of my ignorance!

Comment: +1 for the explanation of bookmarks. I ignored them so far!