# How to save Manipulate bookmarks permanently?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, gui-construction

I would like to save current `Manipulate` parameter values to load them again later. Bookmarks (previously discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13773/a-command-for-outputting-a-list-of-parameter-values-in-a-manipulate-interface/) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13773/a-command-for-outputting-a-list-of-parameter-values-in-a-manipulate-interface/)) work fine until the cell is reinitialized. Is it there a way to save a bookmark permanently and restore it at the next *Mathematica* session?

If not, how could I export a bookmark to a file and import it back? Since the code is huge (more than 80 controls of different types) and constantly evolving, I would like to have it automatized, preferably by a button within the same `Manipulate`.

Many thanks in advance for any useful hints!

Here is a small toy model to play with:

```
Manipulate[ 
    Plot[Fun[2 Pi freq x], {x, 0, 2}, 
        Axes -> showAxes,  
        PlotLabel -> If[showPlotLabel, plotLabel, ""]
      ],
    {Fun, {Sin, Cos}},
    {freq, 1, 3},
    Row[{
       Control[{showAxes, {True, False}}],
       Control[{showPlotLabel, {True, False}}]
       }, "\t"],
     {plotLabel, "Plot Label", Enabled -> showPlotLabel}
     ]
```

Comment: You can change the output cell to `InputForm` and see how the manually added bookmarks ended up as `Bookmarks` option of the `Manipulate`

Comment: @Rojo They are under ``Typeset`bookmarkList$$``. But I'm not sure how to get at the context, since Manipulate does some slight of hand with variable localizations...

Comment: @Ajasja, I meant the input form, the real mathematica expression that is given as a result, not the boxes. You could extract it simply with `Cases["the manipulate", (Bookmarks->b_)->b, Infinity]`

Comment: @Rojo Yes, this returns for example ``{"b1" :> (FE`Fun$$31 = Cos; FE`freq$$31 = 2)}`` but is still not very helpful

Comment: @Ajasja, I'm not really sure what kind of behaviour would be considered helpful and convenient here. Are you? A button that copies the code or that extract the bookmarks code?

Comment: LocalizeVariables -> False  might help. But I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: @Rojo Well, in this case I'm pretty sure (since I work with Iztok:). The OP would like to have a button inside manipulate to easily save all the manipulate control's values to a file and another button that would load the file back. This is most reminiscent of the `Bookmarks` mechanism. The real-life use case is that many people will be using a complex manipulate notebook for some experiential analysis. And will probably not appreciate there bookmarks list being deleted on each redeploy (the redeploys will be frequent at the beginning:)

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks. Will look into that.

Comment: @Ajasja, any difference between loading and storing the controls state+bookmarks and simply storing the whole manipulate?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, the manipulate will evolve over time (fixes will be made, new controls added), but we would like to avoid our end users having to recreate all the bookmarks they have already made.

Comment: @Sorry, I just understood your last comments. Don't look at my answer, it doesn't work that way. I'll ping you two if I edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading some of the comments, I thought I'd post this solution I had done some years ago.  It does not work through the Bookmarks.  As noted, that requires converting things like `` FE`a$$712 `` to `` $CellContext`a$$ `` -- someone may know how to do that easily.  I suspect it could be done.

The code below accomplishes the same intention as the OP.  It saves the current state in a cell, and it can read the cell when the Manipulate is reevaluated.  The cell is identified by a tag.  If it doesn't exist, one is created at the current insertion point when the "Save" button is clicked.

Drawbacks: You have to define what a state is in the code -- in the example, it's `{a, b}`, which appears in both the save and reset button/menu actions.  That can be inconvenient if in development you add and subtract a lot of variables.  One also might wish the cell with the bookmarks was hidden.

```
SelectCellWithTag[tag_] := 
  If[NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], tag, Next, CellTags, 
     AutoScroll -> False] =!= $Failed, 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False],
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell, 
    AutoScroll -> False]; 
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    Cell[BoxData["{}"], "Input", CellTags -> {tag}, 
     ShowCellTags -> True],
    All, AutoScroll -> False];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False]
   ];
ReadCellContents[] := ToExpression@NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]];

Manipulate[
 a + b,
 {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},
 {{save, SelectCellWithTag["BOOKMARKS"]; ReadCellContents[]}, 
  Button["Save", SelectCellWithTag["BOOKMARKS"]; 
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     ToBoxes[save = Append[ReadCellContents[], {a, b}]], 
     AutoScroll -> False]] & },
 {reset, ActionMenu["Reset", (#1 :> ({a, b} = #1) & ) /@ save, 
    Appearance -> "PopupMenu"] & },
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]
[image: BOOKMARKS cell]

**Addendum**

Combining an idea from @Ajasja with the above, the following perhaps does the trick using bookmarks:

```
SelectCellWithTag[tag_] := 
  If[NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], tag, Next, CellTags, 
     AutoScroll -> False] =!= $Failed, 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False], 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell, 
    AutoScroll -> False];
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[ExportString[{}, "Package"]], "Input", 
     CellTags -> {tag}, ShowCellTags -> True], All, 
    AutoScroll -> False];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False]];
ReadCellContents[] := ToExpression@NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]];

Manipulate[a + b, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
 Button["Save bookmarks", SelectCellWithTag["BOOKMARKS"];
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   ToBoxes[StringReplace[
     ExportString[Typeset`bookmarkList$$, "Package"], 
     Shortest["FE`" ~~ v : ___ ~~ "$$"] ~~ DigitCharacter ... :> "$CellContext`" <> v <> "$$"]], 
   AutoScroll -> False]], 
 Button["Restore bookmarks", SelectCellWithTag["BOOKMARKS"];
  Typeset`bookmarkList$$ = ImportString@ReadCellContents[]], 
 Initialization :> (SelectCellWithTag["BOOKMARKS"];
   Typeset`bookmarkList$$ = ImportString@ReadCellContents[]), 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I think if you change your variables during development, even bookmarks may become invalid.

*Edits*: 1. Added button as asked in comment. 2. Improved the `StringReplace` pattern after suggestion by @iztok.

Comment: +1 thanks, although as you mentioned, having to define the variables to be saved manually might get problematic...

Comment: I like the idea, thanks. But - as Ajasja mentioned - we will try to avoid manual listing of all variables since they will surely be changing frequently, and introducing a new source of potential trouble to take care of is not desired. However, if anyone gets around the conversion you noted above, this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: @Ajasja See the alternative I added.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 great idea. Is it possible to have a button to restore the bookmarks inside manipulate?

Comment: @Ajasja  Seed edit.  I put the `Initialization` into the action of a `Button`.  You can remove `Initialization` if you don't want the saved bookmarks automatically loaded.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! This works.

Comment: @MichaelE2 This is certainly the best solution - many thanks!

Comment: @MichaelE2 I noticed that the rule in ``StringReplace`` above works only with one-character parameter names (as ``a`` and ``b``). I generelized it into ``Shortest["FE`"~~v__~~"$$"~~DigitCharacter..~~WordBoundary] :>``.

Comment: @iztok Thanks.  A typo that went unnoticed because I used only one character variables.

Comment: @iztok I put in a slightly different fix than your suggestion.  Somehow I managed to get a bookmark with the symbol ``FE`b$$`` with no following number, which wouldn't be converted by my pattern or your fix.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Manipulate[
bookm = {"b1":>(Fun=Cos; freq=2)};
Plot[Fun[2 Pi freq x],{x,0,2},Axes->showAxes,PlotLabel->If[showPlotLabel,plotLabel,""]],{Fun,{Sin,Cos}},{freq,1,3},Row[{Control[{showAxes,{True,False}}],Control[{showPlotLabel,{True,False}}]},"\t"],{plotLabel,"Plot Label",Enabled->showPlotLabel},
Bookmarks->bookm,
SaveDefinitions->True
]
```

Comment: Hmm, but this is hard to change from inside `manipulate`. Also, when the original input cell is evaluated all the bookmarks are lost...

Comment: You can add bookmarks through with "Add to Bookmarks" from the + control in the upper right corner. Works like a charm. I understood the OP that this should work on a deployed Manipulate, i.e., there is no input cell anymore really.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a prof of principles that saves the bookmarks (`` Typeset`bookmarkList$$ ``) to a string (it could equally well be a file). 
But it only works if `LocalizeVariables -> False` is used, which is quite a limitation.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Fun[2 Pi freq x], {x, 0, 2}, Axes -> showAxes, 
  PlotLabel -> If[showPlotLabel, plotLabel, ""]], {Fun, {Sin, Cos}}, {freq, 1, 3}, 
 Row[{Control[{showAxes, {True, False}}], 
      Control[{showPlotLabel, {True, False}}]}, "\t"], 
 {plotLabel, "Plot Label", Enabled -> showPlotLabel}, 
 Button["Save", 
  globalString = ExportString[Typeset`bookmarkList$$,  "Package"]; Print@globalString],
     Button["Load", 
      Typeset`bookmarkList$$ = ImportString[globalString,  "Package"]],
 LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

To test, add some bookmarks, press `Save`, reinitialize the manipulate control and press `Load`. Thanks to Rojo and Rolf Mertig for their hints.

Comment: Thanks to all three contributors! Even if `LocalizeVariables->False` is not the cleanest solution, nor is splitting the action between existing `Bookmarks` and `Manipulate` controls, I think I will go with it - at least for the start.

Answer (score 1):

What about something along these lines?

```
Manipulate[ 
    Plot[Fun[2 Pi freq x], {x, 0, 2}, 
        Axes -> showAxes,  
        PlotLabel -> If[showPlotLabel, plotLabel, ""]
      ],
    {Fun, {Sin, Cos}},
    {freq, 1, 3},
    Row[{
       Control[{showAxes, {True, False}}],
       Control[{showPlotLabel, {True, False}}]
       }, "\t"],
     {plotLabel, "Plot Label", Enabled -> showPlotLabel}
     ]//addLoadSaveButtons
```

brings out

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have barely tested it but it seems to be able to load and save  states and bookmarks of `Manipulate` expressions

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[putBookmarks, putOwnValues, getBookmarks, getOwnValues , \
getCellManipulate, replaceCellManipulate, getBookmarksAndOwnValues, \
putBookmaksAndOwnValues, addLoadSaveButtons]

(* puts the specified bookmarks options in a Manipulate *)
putBookmarks[HoldPattern@Manipulate[b__, op : OptionsPattern[]], 
   bookmarks_] := Manipulate[b, Bookmarks :> bookmarks, op];

(* puts the specified variable values options in a Manipulate, if \
they exist.
The format is {Hold[var=value]..} *)
putOwnValues[
   HoldPattern@
    Manipulate[b__, vars : Longest[Except[_?OptionQ, _List] ..], 
     rest___], {Hold[var_ = val_], restVars___}] := putOwnValues[
   Hold[vars] /. 
     HoldPattern[{{var, _, r2___} | var, r___}] :> {{var, val, r2}, 
       r} /. Hold[v___] :>
     Manipulate[b, v, rest],
   {restVars}];
putOwnValues[man_, {}] := man;

(* gets the bookmarks option in a Manipulate *)
getBookmarks[HoldPattern@Manipulate[___, op : OptionsPattern[]]] := 
  With[{res = Bookmarks /. Flatten@{op}}, res /; res =!= Bookmarks];
getBookmarks[_Manipulate] := {};

(* gets the values of the variables that have values in a manipulate. \
Format: {Hold[var=val]} *)
getOwnValues[
  HoldPattern@
   Manipulate[b__, vars : Longest[Except[_?OptionQ, _List] ..], 
    rest___]] := 
 Cases[Hold[vars], {{var_, val_, ___}, ___} :> Hold[var = val]]

(* gets the first manipulate it finds in a preorder depth first \
search of the cell expression *)
getCellManipulate[c_Cell] := 
 With[{res = 
    c /. BoxData[boxes_, ___] :> MakeExpression@boxes /. 
     m_Manipulate :> RuleCondition@Return[m, ReplaceAll]}, 
  res /; res =!= c]

(* replaces all the outermost manipulates in a cell expression by the \
specified manipulate *)
replaceCellManipulate[Cell[BoxData[boxes_, r1___], r2___], 
  mnew_Manipulate] := Cell[BoxData[
   Apply[MakeBoxes,
    MakeExpression@boxes /. m_Manipulate :> mnew], r1], r2]

(* the code speaks for itself *)
getBookmarksAndOwnValues[c_Cell] := 
 getCellManipulate[c] /. 
  man_ :> {"Variables State" -> getOwnValues[man], 
    "Bookmarks" -> getBookmarks[man]}

(* inserts the variables and bookmarks in the outermost manipulates \
of the cell expression *)
putBookmaksAndOwnValues[
  c_Cell, {"Variables State" -> ownVals_, 
   "Bookmarks" -> bookmarks_}] := 
 replaceCellManipulate[c, 
  getCellManipulate[c]~putOwnValues~ownVals~putBookmarks~bookmarks]

(* all of these functions default to $Failed *)
Scan[(Blank@# = $Failed) &, 
  {putBookmarks, putOwnValues, getBookmarks, getOwnValues , 
   getCellManipulate, replaceCellManipulate, getBookmarksAndOwnValues,
    putBookmaksAndOwnValues, addLoadSaveButtons}];

(*You wrap your manipulate with this to add the Save and Load buttons \
on the top*)
addLoadSaveButtons[m_Manipulate] := 
 Labeled[m, 
  Row[{Button["Save", 
     Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", ".wdx"], 
      getBookmarksAndOwnValues@readEvaluationCell[], "WDX"], 
     Method -> "Queued"], 
    Button["Load", 
     writeEvaluationCell[
      putBookmaksAndOwnValues[readEvaluationCell[], 
       Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]]]], Method -> "Queued"]}],
   Top]

writeEvaluationCell[stuff_] /; $VersionNumber >= 9 := 
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], stuff];
writeEvaluationCell[
  stuff_] := (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, 
   EvaluationCell]; NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], stuff])

readEvaluationCell[] /; $VersionNumber >= 9 := 
  NotebookRead@EvaluationCell[];
readEvaluationCell[] := (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, 
   EvaluationCell]; NotebookRead@EvaluationNotebook[])
```

Comment: I think what he is asking is what happens when you re-evaluate the manipulate and then import the bookmarks.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch yes, I now understood he wants to reevaluate the manipulate with perhaps some added controls or tweaks, and be able to import the bookmarks and the common controls' state. This doesn't work for that, but I'm not sure if I should delete it

Comment: Hmm, it's not working for me. After pressing save nothing happens... Aha, got it, only works in MMA9.

Comment: Seems as a neat solution, but I am not at v9 yet ... And I would prefer saving only the settings, not all the graphics and other output, especially to ensure compatibility with upgrades.

Comment: @iztok, the code duuump edit only saves the settings, and works with v8 since the last edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a great option at the end of Manipulate called Bookmarks. I was unaware of this until today.

What you might do in order to see the syntax of how to use it is to set the parameters to a desired value and then click the little + icon on the upper right and invoke the "Add to Bookmarks" option.

Say you give it a name (e.g., MyBookmark). To see what this looks like click the little + icon and again and invoke "Paste Bookmarks".

This will write to the screen the current values of the manipulate parameters.

What you would do then is to change your Manipulate code by adding the Bookmark as an option. It would something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Fun[2 Pi freq x], {x, 0, 2}, Axes -> showAxes, 
  PlotLabel -> If[showPlotLabel, plotLabel, ""]], {Fun, {Sin, 
   Cos}}, {freq, 1, 3}, 
 Row[{Control[{showAxes, {True, False}}], 
   Control[{showPlotLabel, {True, False}}]}, "\t"], {plotLabel, 
  "Plot Label", Enabled -> showPlotLabel},
 Bookmarks -> {"Case 1" :> {freq = 1, Fun = Sin, 
     plotLabel = "Plot Label", showAxes = True, 
     showPlotLabel = False}, 
   "Case 2" :> {freq = 1.508`, Fun = Sin, plotLabel = "Plot Label", 
     showAxes = False, showPlotLabel = True}}]
```