# How to disable "Animate Bookmarks" in a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, animation

Is there any way of disabling the item "Animate Bookmarks" in the control menu (which appears clicking on the + symbol on the top right corner) of a Manipulate?

The rationale for this question is that animating bookmarks can cause errors if you have bookmarks which do not set all parameter values. There is a workaround for this (see [171616](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/animate-bookmarks-which-do-not-set-values-for-all-parameters)), but it may imply a significant loss of elegance and parsimony in the code. This, plus the fact that the "Animate bookmarks" functionality may not add much value, leads me to the question.

Thank you so much in advance,
Luis

Comment: You can remove the menu with `AppearanceElements`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kuba♦, but I would like to use the bookmarks. It's only the "Animate bookmarks" feature that I want to get rid of.

Comment: In the end, inspired by @MichaelE2 's answer to [17951](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17951/how-to-save-manipulate-bookmarks-permanently), I ended up abandoning native bookmarks (i.e. AppearanceElements->None) and implementing my desired functionality with an ActionMenu, such as: ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (x = 1;), "x = 2" :> (x = 2;)}]. Thak you so much for your help